# Create a permanent rule for iptables in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, networking, iptables, firewall

In order to establish connection with my Ubuntu server I have to add the following rule to `iptables`:

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Everything is working until I reboot the workstation.

**My question:**
How to make a permanent `iptables` rule, which will work even after restart?

Is there any way to specify the permanent status of the rule via console or I have to deal with configs?

Answer (score 0):

For simple rules, I find it easiest to add the directive to  `/etc/network/interfaces`

**Example**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1
    post-up iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    post-down iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```